# How to extract the p-value from the scipy result

Tags: python, scipy

I have the following code to run Wilcoxon rank-sum test

```
print stats.ranksums(pre_course_scores, during_course_scores)

RanksumsResult(statistic=8.1341352369246582, pvalue=4.1488919597127145e-16)
```

However, I am interested in extracting the pvalue from the result. I could not find a tutorial about this. Can someone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `pvalue` attribute of the returning object:

```
import scipy.stats as ss
result = ss.ranksums(np.random.randn(10), np.random.randn(10)) 
result.pvalue
Out: 0.44969179796889092
```

I assigned it to a variable but you can directly use  `stats.ranksums(pre_course_scores, during_course_scores).pvalue`.